# Fitting Lightgbm distributed with lgb.train hangs

Tags: lightgbm

I'm trying to learn how to use lightgbm distributed.

I wrote a simple hello world kind of code where I use iris dataset with 150 rows, split it into train (100 rows) and test(50 rows). Then training the train test set are further split into two parts. Each part is fed into two machines with appropriate rank.

The problem I see is that lgb.train hangs.

Here is the code:

```
import argparse
import logging
import lightgbm as lgb
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
import socket

print('lightgbm', lgb.__version__)

HOST = socket.gethostname()
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(HOST)
print("IP=", ip_address)

# looks like lightgbm operates only with ip addresses
IPS = ['10.121.22.166', '10.121.22.83']
assert ip_address in IPS

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 4)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 10000)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 100)
pd.set_option('precision', 5)


def read_train_data(rank):
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    iris_df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
    partition = rank
    assert partition < 2

    separate = 100
    train_df = iris_df.iloc[:separate]
    test_df = iris_df.iloc[separate:]

    separate_train = 60
    separate_test = 30
    if partition == 0:
        train_df = train_df.iloc[:separate_train]
        test_df = test_df.iloc[:separate_test]
    else:
        train_df = train_df.iloc[separate_train:]
        test_df = test_df.iloc[separate_test:]

    def get_lgb_dataset(df):
        target_column = df.columns[-1]
        columns = df.columns[:-1]
        assert target_column not in columns
        print('Target column', target_column)

        x = df[columns]
        y = df[target_column]
        print(x)
        ds = lgb.Dataset(free_raw_data=False, data=x, label=y, params={
            "enable_bundle": False
        })
        ds.construct()
        return ds

    dtrain = get_lgb_dataset(train_df)
    dtest = get_lgb_dataset(test_df)
    return dtrain, dtest


def train(args):
    port0 = 56456

    rank = IPS.index(ip_address)

    print("Rank=", rank, HOST)
    print("RR", rank)

    dtrain, dtest = read_train_data(rank=rank)
    params = {'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
              'class_weight': None,
              'colsample_bytree': 1.0,
              'importance_type': 'split',
              'learning_rate': 0.1,
              'max_depth': 2,
              'min_child_samples': 20,
              'min_child_weight': 0.001,
              'min_split_gain': 0.0,
              'n_estimators': 1,
              'num_leaves': 31,
              'objective': 'regression',
              'metric': 'rmse',
              'random_state': None,
              'reg_alpha': 0.0,
              'reg_lambda': 0.0,
              'silent': False,
              'subsample': 1.0,
              'subsample_for_bin': 200000,
              'subsample_freq': 0,
              'tree_learner': 'data_parallel',
              'num_threads': 48,
              'machines': ','.join([f'{machine}:{port0}' for i, machine in enumerate(IPS)]),
              'local_listen_port': port0,
              'time_out': 120,
              'num_machines': len(IPS)
              }
    print(params)

    logging.info("starting to train lgb at node with rank %d", rank)
    evals_result = {}

    if args.scikit == 1:
        print("Using scikit learn")
        bst = lgb.sklearn.LGBMRegressor(**params)
        bst.fit(
            dtrain.data,
            dtrain.label,
            eval_set=[(dtest.data, dtest.label)],
        )
    else:
        print("Using regular LGB")
        bst = lgb.train(params,
                        dtrain,
                        valid_sets=[dtest],
                        evals_result=evals_result)
    print(evals_result)
    logging.info("finish xgboost training at node with rank %d", rank)
    return bst


def main(args):
    logging.info("starting the train job")
    model = train(args)

    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
    print("OUT", model.__class__)
    try:
        print(model.trees_to_dataframe())
    except:
        print(model.booster_.trees_to_dataframe())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--scikit',
        help='scikit',
        default=0,
        type=int,
    )
    main(parser.parse_args())
```

I can run it with the scikit fit interface by running: python simple_distributed_lgb_test.py --scikit 1
On the two machines. It produces a reasonable result.

However, when I use -- scikit 0 (which uses lgb.train), then fitting just hangs on both nodes. Last messages before it hangs:

```
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 22
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data points in the train set: 40, number of used features: 2
[LightGBM] [Warning] Found whitespace in feature_names, replace with underlines
[LightGBM] [Info] Start training from score 0.873750
```

Is that a bug or an expected behavior? dask.py in lightgbm does use scikit learn fit interface.

I use an overnight master version 3.2.1.99. 5b7a6f3e7150aeb704d1dd2b852d246af3e913a3 tag to be exact from Jul 12.

**UPDATE 1**

I'm trying to dig into the code. So far I see few things:

- scikit.train interface appears to have an extra syncronization step before fitting first tree. lgb.train doesn't have it. Dunno yet where it comes from. *(I see some Network::Allreduce operations)*
- It appears that scikit.train has workers syncronized - each worker knows the correct sizes of the blocks to send and receive during reducescatter operations. For example one the first allreduce worker1 sends 208 blocks and receives 368 blocks of data (*in Linkers::SendRecv*), while worker2 is reversed - sends 368 and receives 208. So allreduce completes fine. ()
- On the contrary, lgb.train has workers not syncronized - each worker has numbers for send and receive blocks during reducescatter at the first DataParallelTreeLearner::FindBestSplits encounter. But they don't match. Worker1 sends 208 abd wants to receive 400. Worker2 sends 192 and wants to receive 176. So, the worker that wants to receive more just hangs. The other worker eventually hangs too.

Possibly it has something to do with lgb.Dataset. That thing may need to have same bins or something. I tried to force it by forcedbins_filename parameter. But it doesn't seem to help with lgb.train.

**UPDATE 2**

Success. If I remove the following line from the example:

```
ds.construct()
```

Everything works. So I guess we can't use construct on Dataset when using distributed training.

Comment: The provided sample code contains unnecessary details that increase the effort needed to answer your question. Please remove things like commented-out code, `pd.set_option()` calls, and any branches of if-else logic where you do not experience this issue. In case you're new to Stack Overflow, please see [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which includes the advice "use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem".

Comment: ok sure. I simplified a little bit. I left some amount of pd.set_option there because I do print pandas dataframes along the code. this makes output nicer.

Comment: Since the original post says you're only observing unexpected / problematic behavior when using distributed training, this sample code could be further simplified by removing any `world_size <= 1` code. Hard-coding the number of estimators (instead of exposing it as a parameter) and hard-coding `world_size=2` would also simplify this while (probably) still reproducing the issue. Please look for these and other opportunities to produce sample code that "uses as little code as possible that still produces the same problem".

Comment: Check. Addressed your suggestion. I left scikit option to parser, so that one can test what works and what doesn't, like I explained in the post. Let me know if you see/need further simplifications. I don't see them immediately